# No iOS simulator or device appear on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ios-simulator, build-server, xamarin.forms

- I'm with business account on build server and visual studio
- My build host is connected:
  On diagnose, just the last step isn't pass, is "out dated"
- The IOS project is the start up project.
- The solution's configuration and platform are "Debug" or "Release" and "IPhoneSimulator" or "IPhone":

Check the attached image.
i362.photobucket.com/albums/oo61/romuloCviel/Captura%20de%20Tela%202015-09-28%20as%2011.05.23.png

On XCode and Mac's Xamarin I can run on simulator or device.

Comment: Visual Studio == MS
Xcode == iOS

Comment: Visual Studio and Xcode are not interchangeable.

Comment: now I get it.. But and now? Something can I do?

Comment: There isn't enough information available to assist given.  I would recommend speaking to someone who has built this project successfully before, or looking for internal project build documentation.  If it IS an iOS project, there must be an instance of Xcode somewhere that is used to build and sign

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the second bullet point is correct as the root cause of the issue, that either the Mac or Visual Studio extension is not at version parity with the other, which can cause this sort of issue.

The best solution would be to check for Xamarin Updates as shown on the following page: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/

You will also want to ensure you are on the same update channel on both the Mac and PC, which can be confirmed using the steps in the above link as well.

If updating on both the Mac and PC does not resolve the issue, then you can use business level support, which is available via your account page at: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription under Support

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it, but when I try to update Xamarin.iOS to visual studio on alpha channel, at the end of the install, it crashes.. And I need to reinstall xamarin again, on stable.

Comment: I can't up anymore. I think it's my VM, Parallels. I'm getting an old version to test.